# How asp-area tag helper works with area routing?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have following HTML

```
<a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Page" asp-action="PageTexts" asp-route-pageId="1">
    Homepage
</a>
```

which generates following `a` attribute with wrong URL address, because `area` is used as an `parameter` and not as an `directory`, so following code does not work.

```
<a href="/Page/PageTexts?pageId=1&area=Admin">Homepage</a>
```

instead what I need is this URL, with `admin` part as a URL prefix

```
/admin/page/pagetexts?pageId=1
```

My routing in **startup.cs** is following

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Admin",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

My Area folder structure is following

[image]

And my Admin controllers has `Area` annotation attribute

```
namespace Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Area("Admin")]
    public class PageController : Controller
```

what am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the UseEndpoints middleware, where I switch `MapControllerRoute` with `MapAreaControllerRoute` and now it works as it should.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
      endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
             name: "Admin",
             areaName: "Admin",
             pattern: "Admin/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

      endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
             name: "default",
             pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

      endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```